# In Scatter Plot Python data plot is shifting from x axis marking

Tags: python, scatter-plot

If there is x axis with marking , plot appears at next grid point , for example My X axis is showing marking 2021, a dot which I wanted above 2021 , appears in the marking of 2022, I am using Google colab,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load your data (Replace with your dataset)
# df_std = ...

# Linear regression models
models = {}
predictions = {}

# Columns to predict
columns_to_predict = ['Group I Pass', 'Group II Pass', 'Both Pass']

# Create a scatter plot for all columns with regression lines
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Iterate over each column to make predictions and create scatter plots
for col in columns_to_predict:
    # Filter data for the column to predict
    train_data = df_std[['CA Inter Exam Year', 'Month', col]].copy()
    train_data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(train_data['Month'], format='%B').dt.month

    # Drop rows with missing values
    train_data.dropna(inplace=True)

    # Prepare data for November 2023
    test_data = pd.DataFrame({'CA Inter Exam Year': [2023], 'Month': [11]})

    # Features and target
    X_train = train_data[['CA Inter Exam Year', 'Month']]
    y_train = train_data[col]
    X_test = test_data[['CA Inter Exam Year', 'Month']]

    # Initialize and fit the model
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Make predictions for November 2023 and round them
    predictions[col] = round(model.predict(X_test)[0])

    # Scatter plot for historical data
    ax.scatter(train_data['CA Inter Exam Year'], train_data[col], label=f'{col} - Historical Data', marker='o', s=50)

    # Scatter plot for predicted value in Nov 2023
    ax.scatter(2023, [predictions[col]], label=f'{col} - Predicted Nov 2023', marker='x', s=50)

    # Plot regression line for historical data
    x_range = np.arange(2019, 2024, 1)  # Range of years
    y_range = model.predict(pd.DataFrame({'CA Inter Exam Year': x_range, 'Month': [11] * len(x_range)}))
    ax.plot(x_range, y_range, linestyle='--', label=f'{col} - Regression Line')

# Remove the duplicate entry for "November 2023" from df_std
df_std = df_std.drop(df_std[(df_std['Month'] == 'November') & (df_std['CA Inter Exam Year'] == 2023)].index)

# Create a new DataFrame with 'November 2023'
november_2023_data = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ['November'], 'CA Inter Exam Year': [2023]})

# Combine Year and Month columns for y-axis labels
november_2023_data['YearMonth'] = november_2023_data['Month'] + ' ' + november_2023_data['CA Inter Exam Year'].astype(str)


# Concatenate the new DataFrame with the existing DataFrame
df_std = pd.concat([df_std, november_2023_data], ignore_index=True)

# Set labels and title for the plot
ax.set_xlabel('YearMonth')
ax.set_ylabel('Pass Numbers')
ax.set_title('Pass Percentage Prediction for November 2023')

# Adjust x-axis labels with rotation
ax.set_xticklabels(df_std['YearMonth'], rotation=45, ha='right')  # Adjust rotation angle here


# Add legend
ax.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# Print the predictions for each column with the desired format
for col, prediction in predictions.items():
    print(f"Prediction for 2023 November {col}: {prediction}")
```

[It is table in excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svGfW.png)

I am expecting to plot the scatter plot showing linear regression of studens passing and predict the future trend and plot both historic and predicted values for Nov 2023